# how to use mutliple service paths in AWS EKS Ingress

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I deployed all my resources in Amazon EKS Cluster, now i want to access each services using ingress.i have 3 micro-services.when i added only one service in ingress yaml file it is working please find that code below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
    name: my-ingress
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"  
spec:
    rules:
    - host: dummy.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: user-api-service
              servicePort: 80
```

the above code is working for me and this i changed the ingress file to support multiple paths. the changed code is below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
    name: my-ingress
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
    rules:
    - host: dummy.elb.amazonaws.com
      http:
        paths: 
          - path: /user(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: user-api-service
              servicePort: 80
```

after this i try to access the service using the below link in postman
http://dummy.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/user/api/user/register

but the postman throwing the error 404

can anyone please help me with this issue? please ask if you need more informations

Comment: What are the exact rewrites that you want to achieve? What is the expected result?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor when i call this post method http://dummy.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/user/api/user/register a user should be registered.what iam expecting is i have a post method in my user-api-service & its route is api/user/register. now i need to access this method through ingress whose external address is dummy.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com now other than user-api-service i have 2 other service as well so i need to give multiple paths for that i need to use regx for that i put nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2" and path: /user(/|$)(.*). but it is not working iam getting 404

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor i managed to solve this issue by using ocelot api gateway and calling this gateway from the Ingress